# Is it just a coincidence that the range of order of magnitude of length and time is $10^{41}$ does it have some explanation?

Tags: order-of-magnitude

> The ratio of the longest and shortest lengths of objects in our universe is about $10^{41}$. Interestingly enough, the ratio of the longest and shortest time intervals associated with the events and objects in our universe is also about $10^{41}$.

> ...The ratio of the largest and smallest masses of the objects in our universe is about $10^{41^{2}}$.

According to Wikipedia articles of [order of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) of [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(length)), [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(time)) and [mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(mass)), If we ignore the subatomic level and limit ourselves to the observable universe in length, time and mass, then we have;

- $10^{-15}$ m is the size of a proton.
- $10^{26}$ m is the distance to the boundary of the observable universe.

The ratio is $\frac{10^{26}}{10^{-15}}$ $=10^{41}$ for [orders of magnitude of length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(length)).

- $10^{-24}$ s is the life span of most unstable particle.
- $10^{17}$ s is the age of the universe.

Again, the ratio is $\frac{10^{17}}{10^{-24}}$ $=10^{41}$ for the [order of magnitude of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(time)).

- $10^{-30}$ kg is the mass of an electron.
- $10^{55}$ kg is the mass of the observable universe.

The ratio of the largest and smallest masses of the objects in our universe is about $10^{41^{2}}$. See [Order of magnitude (mass)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(mass)). Is this a curious coincidence between these large numbers purely accidental? I highly doubt that this may establish some relationship between the fundamental units of length, time, and mass.

Comment: The "observable" universe itself means that it is not the biggest length and there is more to it that we have not yet gotten signals from

Comment: There are several comments. 1) It is not very surprizing that the age of the universe and the size of the observable universe are of the same order (although you should be careful, there is still a factor ~6 difference). 2) Top quark width is 13.1GeV which is at least an order of magnitude bigger (but still close enough) than the QCD scale that controls the size of a proton. 3) The choice of QCD scale 1GeV is somewhat arbitrary. It is obvious that there are even shorter scales: electroweak, gravity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a commonly known observation, which was first made by Paul Dirac almost a hundred years ago: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis. It is called the Dirac Large Numbers Hypothesis.

There has been a lot of speculation, but nobody has presented any conclusive evidence of a deeper connection between the various fundamental constants involved.

Comment: Wow. Did not know this.